# Video not working on html5 media player in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, video, web-applications

I'm trying to play a video using the html5 media player in a web application created using the codeigniter framework. This is what I have so far:

```
      public function view($settings, Screen $screen)
      {
             $view = "<video width='100%'' height='100%'' controls>
                         <source src='application/views/video/Arrow.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
                         Your browser does not support the video tag.
                      </video>";
             return $view;
      }
}
```

I've tried putting the video file in different directories, I've tried adding the mimes for the file type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put video outside of `application` folder.

In MVC architecture, `models` and `views` should not be directly accessible to user, except `controller`.

Create a folder named `videos` in your project root directory, put `Arrow.mp4` file inside that folder and change this code block to get the results.

```
function view ( $settings, $screen )
{
    $view = "<video width='100%' height='100%' controls>
                 <source src='videos/Arrow.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
                 Your browser does not support the video tag.
             </video>";
    echo $view;
}
```

Comment: what issues are you facing? can you elaborate?

Comment: The player itself appears on the page, however the video doesn't play. The controls are grayed out. 
This web application is for internal use, and I'm using chrome as the web browser on all of the machines that I am using this application on. I know that chrome is able to play the file as I've tested this with a seperate web page that simply contains the html5 media player and it works fine.

Comment: right click on your page, click `view source`, check if you can click the link right next to `src`.

Comment: If I open the link next to src in a new tab, it just gives me a 404 message. Its looking at the link as if its in the view directory. Do I need to put it in there instead?

Comment: change `<source src='videos/Arrow.mp4' type='video/mp4'>` to `<source src='{base_url()}videos/Arrow.mp4' type='video/mp4'>`

Comment: I tried what you suggested again but with the base url manually put in. I then went to view source as before opened the link next to src in a new tap and it said it couldn't find the page. However if I put the address into the browser myself, it works.

Comment: what is your `src` rendering after above mentioned solution ?

Comment: Just the media player

Answer (score 0):

```
function view ($settings, $screen )
{
  $url = base_url()
    $view = "<video width='100%' height='100%' controls>
                <source src=".$url."'assets/video/Arrow.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
                 Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>";
    return $view;
}
```

Place all videos outside application folder. and call it back.

So Your folder Structurer would change like

1. application
2. assets

   - video
   - css
   - JS
   - images
3. system
4. index.php
5. .htacess

**Extra note :**

in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: I've just tried this as you suggested, however it's still not working

Comment: check  with `return $view;`

Comment: I know that `return $view` is working as the media player is showing up on the page. Its just the video file that isn't playing. (Is that what you were asking?)

Comment: without controller you can play your video in view. `<video width='100%' height='100%' controls><source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>'assets/video/Arrow.mp4" type='video/mp4'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>`

Comment: I tried `<source src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>'assets/video/Arrow.mp4" type='video/mp4'>` but it then just doesn't work at all, no media player, nothing.

Comment: No its woking well in my code. Check your names are not mixed with caps and small caps

Comment: I've managed to get it to work outside of codeigniter, but with the same file structure. Inside codeigniter I still can't get it to work. I've even tried it with copying your code directly from the above and pasting it into the file, still no luck. I've check the names of the file and the directories.

Comment: You can show the video directly in your view. Why you are using controler to show it up??

Comment: Its part of a "widget/template" system. The widgets are the content of the templates and the templates define the view. What I'm trying to do is create a video widget for this web app

Answer (score 0):

What I got to work for me is to create an assets/video/ directory in the project root.

```
<video controls loop>
<source src="assets/video/videofile.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Specifically referencing the assets folder as "assets" instead of referencing as `C:/xampp/htdocs/projectfolder/assets/video/"`. If I reference the full path, it did NOT work.